# Gatling scenario to check status, then response header. Use `checkIf`?

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm looking to create a scenario where it does the following rate limiting test:

1. Makes a request every second
2. Checks the status
3. If the status is `200`, nothing further
4. If the status is `429`, then assert that a new response header appears (`X-Ratelimited`)

This is how my scenario is set up so far:

```
val throttleTest = scenario("Throttle access-code").during(60 seconds) {
    exec(http("put")
      .put("/auth/code")
      .check(
        checkIf(status.is(429))(header("X-Ratelimited"))
      )
      .body(StringBody(s"""{"foo": "$bar"}""")))
      .pause(1)
  }
```

Currently this gives me an error:

```
overloaded method value checkIf with alternatives:
  [R, C <: io.gatling.core.check.Check[R]](condition: (R, io.gatling.core.session.Session) => io.gatling.commons.validation.Validation[Boolean])(thenCheck: C)(implicit cw: io.gatling.core.check.TypedConditionalCheckWrapper[R,C])C <and>
  [C <: io.gatling.core.check.Check[_]](condition: io.gatling.core.session.Expression[Boolean])(thenCheck: C)(implicit cw: io.gatling.core.check.UntypedConditionalCheckWrapper[C])C
 cannot be applied to (io.gatling.core.check.CheckBuilder[io.gatling.http.check.status.HttpStatusCheckType,io.gatling.http.response.Response,Int])
        checkIf(status.is(429))(header("X-Ratelimited"))
```

Should I be using `checkIf` in this case, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the current `checkIf` correctly.
There's no version of `checkIf` that takes a check as the first parameter, see [doc](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/#conditional-checking).

As of Gatling 3.5, you have to craft the condition yourself:

```scala
checkIf((response: Response, _: Session) => response.status.code == 429) {
  header("X-Ratelimited")
}
```

Your idea is interesting though. Maybe we could leverage what we do with [matching](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/websocket/#matching-messages) for WebSockets in a future version.

Comment: This is cool, thank you. Could you elaborate more on what is going on with `response: Response, _: Session) =>` ?

Comment: That's a lambda that has 2 input parameters: the Response and the Session (_ because it's unused) and returns a Boolean.